# Finding general solution to system of ODEs using complex eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the eigenvalue method to find the general solution to the initial value problem:

$x_1' = 3x_1-5x_2$

$x_2' = 5x_1+3x_2$

$x_1(0) = 1$ and $x_2(0) = 4$

I found complex eigenvalues $\lambda=3-5i$ and $\lambda = 3+5i$ which have corresponding eigenvectors $\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1\\i \end{array} \right]$ and $\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1\\-i \end{array} \right]$.  Now I'm not sure how I can write the general solution.  Does it involve both eigenvectors?

Comment: you need to take real and imaginary parts of your solution. These two will be linearly independent real-valued solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're solving $x'(t) = A x(t)$, and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $x(t) = e^{\lambda t} v$ is a solution:
\begin{align*}
x'(t) &= \lambda e^{\lambda t} v \\
&= e^{\lambda t} A v \\
&= A x(t).
\end{align*}

With your two eigenvectors, you can get two solutions in this manner.  Any linear combination of those two solutions is also a solution.  So choose the coefficients in that linear combination to satisfy your initial conditions.

Here's a different explanation. You know a basis of eigenvectors of $A$, so you can factor $A$ as $A=U \Lambda U^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal.  (The columns of $U$ are eigenvectors of $A$, and the diagonal elements of $\Lambda$ are corresponding eigenvalues of $A$.)  Now let $y(t) = U^{-1}x(t)$ and solve for $y$. The system has decoupled, and you can solve for the components of $y$ separately.

Comment: How can I ensure that my solutions are real-valued, though?  $e^{(3-5i)t}$ surely isn't real.

Comment: I think a uniqueness theorem guarantees that there is only one solution to your ODE (together with your two initial conditions).  Also, an existence theorem tells us there is a real-valued solution.  So, if you find any solution, it must be the real-valued solution (which is unique).  In other words, if you just satisfy those initial conditions, your solution will turn out to be real.  Let me know if I'm mistaken though.

Comment: @user1038665 Yes, since the complex eigenvalues will come in a conjugate pair, as will the eigenvector , the general solution will be real valued. [See here](http://www.smast.umassd.edu/CMMS/Courses/MAR580/Lectures/Lecture_22.pdf) for an example.